# Using view.getId(), which changes randomly

Tags: android

So I have used the `view.getId()` in order to achieve changing the  I have, like this:

```
public void changeLinear(View view) {
    layoutPrimer.setVisibility(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    layoutSegon.setVisibility(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    layoutPostre.setVisibility(view.getId() == R.id.btnPostres ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    layoutExtra.setVisibility(view.getId() == R.id.btnExtres ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

I'm trying to implement the same logic in: `view.getId() == R.id.btn..` by being able to clear a radioGroup while in the same  I have defined:

```
public void displayFalse(View view) {

    if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers){
        rgPrimer.clearCheck();
    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSegons){
        rgSegon.clearCheck();
    }else if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPostres) {
        rgPostre.clearCheck();
    } else {
        swcTriaExtra1.setChecked(false);
        swcTriaExtra2.setChecked(false);
        swcTriaExtra3.setChecked(false);
        swcTriaExtra4.setChecked(false);
        swcTriaExtra5.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

But the thing is that this second view.getId() is different than the one I get in the function up top, being 7f070027 the one on the top and 7f070022.

So, without changing the view at anytime, I have different view.getId(). So when I want to get in the conditional: `if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers)` in the second function, it won't get in because somehow it is different.

How do these view id's work? How could I overcome this issue? Is there a improved version?

Comment: You could use Android:tag in your xml and give each view a unique tag to check that wont change.

Comment: I am already using the tag, I need something else

Comment: You mean that the same view seems to have 2 different ids in the 2 methods?

Comment: Yes @forpas, i'm a newbie, that might be normal but atleast I thought that would always be the same in the same view.

Comment: It is the same. I'm not sure if every time you run the app the ids could be different, but as long as the app is "on" the id retains the same value for the same view.

Comment: But I don't understand why is this of any importance. You don't need to know the actual int value of the id. All you need is `R.id.someid`. Maybe you must clarify what is the problem.

Comment: Is that better? I really don't know how to explain something which I don't understand yet.. :/ I'm doing my best

Comment: So you mean that you call `displayFalse(btnPrimers)` and this `if(view.getId() == R.id.btnPrimers)` fails?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183026/discussion-between-raul-and-forpas).

Comment: Add your layout xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you never call View.setId(), then [View.getId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId())() should return to you the value assigned to the view with `android:id` in the layout file. This should not change during your application's lifetime (except after rebuilding the application).

I suspect what is going on here is that, in the second comparison, you are actually comparing the view ID of a child View, which of course will be different than its parent.

For debugging purposes, you might consider using [Resource.getResourceName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceName(int)) to see the human-readable name associated with the View:

```
getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
```